Why has NATO ignored Russia moving Estonian buoys?
According to the Estonian Police and Border Guard, Russia has moved the  buoys from Narva River
https://www.politsei.ee/en/news/border-guard-of-the-russian-federation-removed-light-buoys-from-narva-river-11981
These buoys aren't there for the exclusive purpose of guiding fishing and shipping routes. They are also there to mark territorial rights to the river.
https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2024-05-23/estonia-says-russia-removed-narva-river-buoys-marking-border
The EU (who knows they may be next in the Russian war expansion) has indeed responded by saying this is unacceptable
https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/c899844ypj2o
The question is  why Estonia's  NATO partners do not also comment on the removal of a member countries border demarcations. Such an action and the potential outcome can greatly affect them in the future as well.

We're Friday and this happened Thursday morning local time.  Maybe wait a bit next time before asking a breathless "why was nothing done?" question?

International reaction   rarely starts  a few days later . The media hysteria usually starts immediately. You saw it here first. There is not going to be any major reaction to Russia moving Estonian border demarcation lines

It's been about a month since. As predicted it was ignored.

The formal answer:
Major NATO reactions would start if a member invokes either Article 4 or Article 5 of the NATO treaty. The member to do that in this case would likely be Estonia. As of 2024-05-24, I am not aware of them doing so.
The political answer:
Russian propaganda is trying to characterize the Russian war of aggression against Ukraine as a preemptive war against NATO. There are daily Russian provocations. Getting publicly excited about every little provocation plays into their strategy.
(These days, it would be newsworthy if they don't threaten nuclear war ...)

Who says NATO said nothing?.

Estonia is a member of the North Atlantic Treaty Organization, and NATO Secretary General Jens Stoltenberg said he spoke with Estonian Prime Minister Kaja Kallas, saying the bloc stands "in solidarity" with the nation "against any threat" to its sovereignty.

Now, how far should this affair be pushed about pigs, sorry, buoys?

"I will involve two great nations in a war over a squabble about a pig."

This is traditional provocations, a la Cold War.  Everyone knows where the border is.  Far from the worst thing Russia has been up to lately, even directly involving NATO states, rather than Ukraine (cough, Skripals, cough).  It's important to put the Russians on notice that they are being watched, not so much to escalate things overmuch.  In practical terms, why not spend more energy sending weapons to Ukraine instead?
